# Efficiency of using built in functions like countif vs worksheet functions

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning Excel VBA and I recently learned about using range.value as opposed to the copy paste method in VBA which has dramatically increased the efficiency of my code.

Does use of functions like countif? or anything with a prefix worksheetfunction suffer from the same efficiency drawbacks as doing the

```
range.select
range.copy
range.paste
```

or am I comparing apples and oranges.

If it is not as efficient, is there a more efficient way than hard coding the algorithm of a function like countif?

Comment: I think I know what you're getting at, so let me clarify - but please correct me if I'm off-base:

If you are trying to increase the efficiency not only of your script, but also in the speed of how your **spreadsheet** works, as well, I'd recommend looking into `PasteSpecial` as well (under the `Range` method), and see about using `copy` and `paste` to `Fill` down your cells, then `copy` the `range` but `PasteSpecial` the `Values` in place of the formula.

Comment: Yes, using a worksheet function from VBA code will *always* be less efficient than running native VBA code (ok, not always, except for  with very few exceptions you have to really try to make a VBA function slower than a worksheet function called from VBA code)